# Developer related changes to prepare for Ethereum hard fork - Constantinople

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am hosting my own ethereum node using `geth` and I have some simple `dApps` which make use of the `web3.js` library.

I went through various documentations related to the hard fork, more specifically this one https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/01/11/ethereum-constantinople-upgrade-announcement/

I understand that I have to upgrade my `geth` node to `v1.8.20` https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases

Apart from this, do I need to update anything else?

Answer (score 0):

if you are running the dapps on mainnet, there is nothing to be done from your end w.r.t to code. Please follow below steps

1. Stop your geth console where you chain is running
2. Update your geth to latest version (1.8.23 current latest version)
3. restart your geth console

You are all set and Constantinople fork is set for you geth console. Once you start you geth console, you can view it in admin.nodeInfo, the config contains constantinopleBlock: 7280000.

Hope this helps